# How to count number of comparisons in a quicksort algorithm?

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of comparisons made with a quicksort algorithm. To my understanding, it should take about 1000 comparisons to sort an array with 80 elements. Right now with what I have, it is spitting out 80 elements takes about 250 comparisons. This doesn't seem right. I'm assuming my counts are in the wrong place, but I really don't know. I know that some of the code isn't here, but it would be way to long if I added everything. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public void quickSort(int[] data) {
    quickSort(data, 0, data.length - 1);
}
private void quickSort(int[] data, int min, int max) {
    if (min < max) {
        // create partitions
        int indexofpartition = partition(data, min, max);

        // sort the left partition (lower values)
        quickSort(data, min, indexofpartition - 1);

        // sort the right partition (higher values)
        quickSort(data, indexofpartition + 1, max);
    }
}

private int partition(int[] data, int min, int max) {
    int partitionelement;
    int left, right;
    int middle = (min + max) / 2;

    // use the middle data value as the partition element
    partitionelement = data[middle];

    // move it out of the way for now
    swap(data, middle, min);

    left = min;
    right = max;

    while (left < right) {
        
        // search for an element that is > the partition element
        while (left < right && data[left] <= partitionelement) 
            left++;
            count++;

        // search for an element that is < the partition element
        while (data[right] > partitionelement) 
            right--;
            count++;

        // swap the elements
        if (left < right) 
            swap(data, left, right);

    }

    // move the partition element into place
    swap(data, min, right);
    return right;
    
}
```

Comment: Add braces after the while statement, so for example left++ and count++ are executed together. Now your count will always be executed twice.

Comment: It should take n lg n comparisons on average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add braces to your inner while loop. Currently only `left++` and `right--` is getting executed inside the loop. Updated code would be like:

```
    // search for an element that is > the partition element
    while (left < right && data[left] <= partitionelement) {
        left++;
        count++;
    }

    // search for an element that is < the partition element
    while (data[right] > partitionelement && right >= min) {
        right--;
        count++;
    }
```

**Additional hint:** Add a check for the index in the second while loop. Else, it can throw an exception if there isn't any value lesser than the `partitionelement`.